# Table won't alter when using psycopg

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm having some trouble altering tables in my postgres database. I'm using psycopg2 and working out of Python. I tried to add a serial primary key. It took a long time (large table), and threw no error, so it did *something*, but when I went to check, the new column wasn't there.

I'm hoping this is something silly that I've missed, but right now I'm at a total loss.

```
import psycopg2
username = *****
password = *****
conn = psycopg2.connect(database='mydb',user=username,password=password)
query = "ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN sid serial PRIMARY KEY"
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(query)
conn.close()
```

Other things I've tried while debugging:

- It doesn't work when I remove PRIMARY KEY.
- It doesn't work when try a different data type.

Comment: Did you try to `conn.commit()` before closing the connection?

Comment: Your session is probably not in autocommit mode.  You should either change that or explicitly commit the change.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add a commit statement in order for your changes to reflect in the table. Add this before you close the connection.

```
conn.commit()
```